# Question on the 2002 Engle paper regarding GARCH-DCC model

Tags: econometrics, garch, cross-correlation

Paper here, please open using Incognito tab: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=236998 press "Download this paper" button

***Let me sum up the core of that paper*** in simple words :
Unlike regular GARCH, GARCH-DCC states that the vector of the residuals of another model (ECM in my case) should follow a multivariate normal law with a time varying variance-covariance matrix $H_t$ :

$$\begin{pmatrix}
   \epsilon_1 \\
   \vdots \\ 
   \epsilon_n
\end{pmatrix} \sim N(0,H_t) $$

$H_t$ is defined as $H_t = D_tR_tD_t$ and
$D_t$ is the diagonal matrix containing all the conditional standard deviations at time $t$, retrieved simply by regular GARCH models, one for each asset. $R_t$ is the time varying matrix of conditional correlation. Hence, $H_t$ is a variance-covariance matrix as expected in the input of the normal multivariate.

Engle defines a $Q_t$ being recursively equal to : $Q_t =\overline{R}(1 - \alpha - \beta) + \alpha v_{t-1}v_{t-1}'+\beta Q_{t-1} $ he says it's the specification of the GARCH-DCC. $v_{t}$ represent the vector of standardized residual by their conditional standard deviation retrieved in D. It's just a vector of Z-scores instead of a vector of unit-varying variables.

Then, instead of using that $Q_t$ directly in the $H_t = D_tR_tD_t$ as I would have expected ($Q_t$ would be implicitly be at the place of $R_t$, since it's the time varying variance-covariance matrix), he standardize the element of $Q_t$ to get that final $R_t$ with this standardization (Eq. (21) in the paper)
$$r_{ij,t}= \frac{q_{ij,t}}{\sqrt{q_{ii}q_{jj}}}$$

I do understand that using the raw $Q_t$ is not a correlation matrix stricto sensu because last period cross product brings elements out of [-1: 1], even if their expected value is in this bound.

What I don't understand precisely is:

- (1) why this Engle standardization in particular would make the diagonal of R to 1, and the elements in [-1; 1] as we want ?
- (2) Even if (1) is admitted, he provides page 10 (IV, Estimation) another specification for R_t:
  $$R_t = \operatorname{diag}(Q_t)^{-1} Q_t \operatorname{diag}(Q_t)^{-1}$$ : this does not correspond, unless I'm mistaken, to the transformation from Q to R provided above (in equation (21) of the paper)

Could someone clear my mind about these problems for my thesis?